# Change port Context Broker mongo

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Good, I changed the access port to mongodb and now the contextBroker does not load me mongo since I understand that by default this is 27017

How can I change the port of the mongo contextBroker to new?

Error:

```
{
     "error": "InternalServerError",
     "description": "Database Error (collection: orion.entities - count (): {_id.id: & quot; ARMpalmerillas07 & quot ;, _id.type: & quot; GreenHouse & quot ;, _id.servicePath: {$ in: [/ ^ / ARMpalmerillas $ /]}} - exception: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for localhost: 27017 (127.0.0.1) failed) "
}
```

a greeting

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information like how are you running Orion Context Broker? Are you using a VM image? Perhaps a Docker Image? As a service from yum repositories?

Comment: Hello,

The version I use is 1.19 and the way to launch it is like this: contextBroker -corsOrigin __ALL

I'll do the compilation. since it is not available since version 1.7 in the yum repository

Comment: Last Orion version released up to know is 1.12... I guess you refer to 1.9, isn't it? :)

Comment: I understand you change the DB port *while* Orion was running... otherwise Orion shouldn't have started (it checks DB connection at startup and refuses to start if it cannot connect).

Comment: I'm sorry I wanted to say 1.10

Comment: Hello,

At the time of the change if the contextBroker was running

my problem is that I changed the mongo configuration both the IP and the port ..

I am not able to restart the contextBroker since it is not an installation with yum and it is not a service.

Any suggestions to restart it?

Answer (score 1):

I never tried to change default port of Mongo, but I can see in the  [official documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/running/index.html) of Orion Context Broker that there is a property called **BROKER_DATABASE_HOST** that you could change to point to specific Mongo running instance. Then use your Mongo host and port instead of default values  localhost and 27017.

I would try to change the value of this property with something like this:

```
BROKER_DATABASE_HOST=x.x.x.x:my_port
```

Also if you are running Orion Context Broker from source code I think that you could pass your values as arguments to the binary like this:

```
sudo contextBroker -db orion -dbhost localhost:my_port -dbuser user -dbpwd password
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I can not find the context Broker configuration in the route:
/ etc / sysconfig / contextBroker

Any ideas?

Comment: Try the second option that I mentioned you, passing dbhost as an argument to contextBroker in your execution command.

sudo contextBroker -db orion -dbhost localhost:my_port -dbuser user -dbpwd password

For example: sudo contextBroker -db orion -dbhost localhost:27018

Comment: Probably, you don't need to run the command with sudo (except in the case you are trying to use some privileged resource, e.g. run Orion listenen on a port < 1024).

Comment: I have tried the following and it does not work:

sudo contextBroker -db orion -dbhost 1xx.2xx.1xx.xx0: 8181

Comment: With or without whitespace between ":" and ":8181" ?

Comment: It was a mistake to copy it. but there is not that space.

How can I start the service again ?, restart it.